Where is the updated documentation for SPM integration>?
In release notes for version 8.1.0 I see this statement:

MarketingCloudSDK Integration via SPM – Integration via Swift Package Manager (SPM) now automatically includes SFMCSDK, simplifying integration efforts.

However, the documentation doesn't seem to be updated with steps to integrate with SPM. The Package.swift file is not present in the default GitHub branch (master) so I assume we need to use some branch/tag requirement in the Package.swift entry when adding the dependency.
For instance, adding this line to my Package.swift file dependencies:
.package(url: "https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS", branch: "spm"),
Gives me two errors:

Revision eae011c612c69a623c6f34e17c3740cc40677cd6 for sfmc-sdk-ios
remoteSourceControl
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-sdk-ios version
1.1.2 does not match previously recorded value 82442570dc238cdf938b61bd0fa860db31c52fe3

And

x-xcode-log://FE8D3F8D-FA66-4161-AC57-25BD7C07DB20 binary target
'MarketingCloudSDK' could not be mapped to an artifact with expected
name 'MarketingCloudSDK'

Anyway, all of this it's a lot of guessing.
Could you please provide the updated info in the docs?

Starting SDK version 8.1.0, When MarketingCloudSDK is added to SPM, the SDK automatically downloads its dependant SFMCSDK. You may have remove the prior version of SFMCSDK from the dependendencies.
Also, Please make sure the caches are cleared as Xcode caches the packages.
Thanks,
Prakashini

Yes. But which is the package URL I should use to add the package? Does it work also if I add it as dependency to another package?
I've tried many options and none of them worked, as described in the question.
